# Possible ways to identify RewriteRule when both files are in the same folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Ok this maybe sound like the worst question on stackoverflow but here it is.

In a folder `offers` I have those files:

```
product.php
category.php
```

To display a product I type `domain.com/offers/product.php?id=1` and
to display a category, I type `domain.com/offers/category.php?id=1`

Because this url looks ugly I rewrite for example the product.php using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

and this gives me a `domain.com/offers/1`

Because `product.php` and `category.php` are in the same folder and both gets a numeric variable, that means it will not execute correctly.

So a possible way is to have a `slug` for `category.php` and keep the `id` for `product.php` and then write some code for it.

My question is, is this the only way ?

**Update**
I didn't tried it but what if I have the one as `product.php?pid=1` and the other `category.php?cid=1` ?

Comment: The problem isn't in the real URL of the page (pid/cid instead of id), but in the URL that the user sees. In both cases, it sounds like you're trying to get `domain.com/offers/???` to redirect to either products *or* categories, but it doesn't work like that; there needs to be something in the *displayed URL* that tells the RewriteRule where it's supposed to go. ...Sure hope any of that made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to differentiate them in the URL. This scheme would make the URLs into:

```
example.com/offers/category/1
example.com/offers/product/99
```

Done via:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^offers/(product|category)/([a-z0-9]+)?$ $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The first group `(product|category)` captures the destination script, which is translated to `$1.php`. The second group is translated to to the associated id.

#### Update

You don't have to have them appear as separate directories `/products, /categories` but you do have to have some way of differentiating them. Instead you can place a `p` or `c` at the start of the ID number:

```
example.com/offers/c1
example.com/offers/p99
```

Done via:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^offers/p([a-z0-9]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^offers/c([a-z0-9]+)?$ category.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Or you can expand them out to

Comment: Does it have to be in a different folder? Category folder and product folder?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some difference in the displayed URL. Something like...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9]+)$ category.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Meaning that product.php will be accessed from `domain.com/offers/1` and category.php from `domain.com/category/1` ?